# Jenkins PER USER default parameter values?

Tags: jenkins, parameters, build, continuous-integration

We are using a parameterized Jenkins build job, and I would like to have default values for some parameters specific for myself, e.g. the dev branch name I mostly use. Is it possible? We do have personal users in Jenkins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by:

1. Create a scriptler which checks the current user and returns the appropriate value:

   ```
   def user = jenkins.model.Jenkins.getAuthentication().getName();
   def returnValue
   switch (user) {
      case ['user1','user2']:
        returnValue = 'xyz'
        break;
      case ['user3']:
        returnValue = 'abc'
        break;
      default:
        returnValue = '00'
      break;  
   }
   return returnValue
   ```

   If you want to use the [Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) your script will need to return a list:

   ```
   def user = jenkins.model.Jenkins.getAuthentication().getName();
   def returnValue = [];
   switch (user) {
      case ['user1','user2']:
        returnValue << 'xyz'
        break;
      case ['mtlelj']:
       returnValue << 'abc'
       break;
      default:
        returnValue << '00'
      break;  
   }
   return returnValue
   ```
2. Configure your parameterized build to have a **Dynamic Parameter (Scriptler)** or an **Active Choices** parameter and reference the script you created as it's source.

If you don't want a script centrally managed by admins, the Active Choices Parameter allows you to use the code within the parameter definition. I'm using:
**Jenkins ver** 2.32.3
**Scriptler Plugin ver** 2.9
**Dynamic Parameter Plugin ver** 2.9
**Active Choices Plugin ver** 2.9

Comment: thanks! Could it be an "Active Choice Parameter" in my version? I'm using 2.119

Comment: Answer updated with example for Active Choice that worked for my build.

Comment: seems that I don't have the Dynamic Parameter plugin installed. I'll look into it. Thanks again

Comment: "Distribution of this plugin has been suspended due to unresolved security vulnerabilities" :(

Comment: It'll work with the https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin (still distributed), using the 2nd code example.