# Is it possible for single Jenkins job have different check list for different users?

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to configure single Jenkins job with blow conditions?

1. I have two set of Jenkins users  (QA & Dev) and different set of nodes (servers) for each  QA & Dev teams.
2. QA teams don't have privileges to deploy a build to Dev node and vise versa.
3. Jenkins job is Parameterized job, users can enter different node (IP) when Jenkins job run.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can use the [JENKINS Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin).

The idea is to propose a different list of node IPs depending on the first field (QA/DEV)

The first step of the job will be to test the user team, and fail the job if the user is not in the right team compared to the first field value (QA/DEV)

Answer (score 0):

Variation on above, but without the need to check and fail. You can use a scriptler script and the [Jenkins Active Choices Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) to return a list of allowed nodes based on the current logged in user, either as a centrally administered script, or just defined in the parameter definition.

Similar to the answer to this question: [jenkins-per-user-default-parameter-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50894926/jenkins-per-user-default-parameter-values/50904576#50904576), Your scriptler would look something like:

```
def user = jenkins.model.Jenkins.getAuthentication().getName();
switch (user) {
   case ['user1','user2']:
     return ['node1','node2'] 
     break;
   case ['user3','user4']:
     return ['node3','node4'] 
    break;
   default:
    return null
   break;  
}
```

Then configure an 'Active Choices Parameter' with the scriptler script or code as the source. I'm using:

**Jenkins ver** 2.32.3
**Scriptler Plugin ver** 2.9
**Dynamic Parameter Plugin ver** 2.9
**Active Choices Plugin ver** 2.9